# How to stop Android action bar logo and title being transparent

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I'm using the compat library to add an action bar to an app. I have set a custom theme which extends Theme.AppCompat and set a background for the action bar and a background for the application. However the action bar icon and title backgrounds seems to be transparent which means the app background is visible through the action bar as you can see below. Any ideas?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: please provide some code